# Flutter web app encounters error when sending GET request with body

Tags: flutter, dart, http, web, flutter-http

I'm currently developing  `a Flutter web application`  where I've encountered **an issue specifically when attempting to send a GET request with a body**. The application works as expected on Chrome, but upon **sending this particular request**, I consistently receive an error indicating that **the body is empty**.

I've tried using both the `HTTP` and `Dio` packages, and I've also added the `' Access-Control-Allow-Origin'` header to handle cross-origin issues, but the problem persists. Is there a known workaround or solution to successfully **send GET requests with bodies in Flutter web apps**? Any insights, code samples, or alternative approaches would be immensely helpful. Thank you!

********** **Edit** **********

Get with body work in `ANDROID` and `IOS`

```
   //sample code
    Map<String, String> header = {};

    String? token = SharedPrefsHelper.getString(prefToken);

    String langCode = SharedPrefsHelper.getString(prefLanguageCode) ?? 
     "ar";

    header['content-type'] = 'application/json';
    header["Authorization"] = "bearer $token";
    header["Accept-Language"] = langCode;

    final request = Request('GET', 
    Uri.parse(url))..headers.addAll(header);
    request.body = json.encode(parameter);
    final response = await request.send()
```

Comment: Please replace the word body in the question with header, as you are using headers and not a body in the example.

Comment: I edited the question, I added the request body @Jannik

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Future reader**

> Some security mechanisms, such as web application firewalls (WAFs) or
> proxies, might be configured to block or modify GET requests with
> bodies due to security concerns.

If you are trying to send data with a request, especially if it involves a request body, it's more appropriate to use a `POST` request. `The POST` method is designed for submitting data to be processed to a specified resource.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot (or at least should not) send a body with a get request [see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/978061/http-get-with-request-body?rq=2). The http package cannot do it [see](https://pub.dev/documentation/http/latest/http/BaseClient/get.html) and dio aswell [see](https://pub.dev/documentation/dio/latest/dio/Dio/get.html).

If you want to send data with a get request, you should use query parameters.

Comment: Request `Get` with body work as expected in Android and IOS , You can see the sample code.I edited the question

Comment: I have edited the answer. Consider replacing the body with query parameters, `Get` requests should not have a body.

Comment: We attempted to include the body in the query parameters, but it still did not work. Finally, we replaced our `GET` request with a `POST` request, and now it is functioning correctly @Jannik

Comment: Great that it works now. Please look into the http verbs if `POST` is the appropriate choice for your use case. Normally, verbs cannot (should not) be used interchangeably.